# Rect build warning : autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead

Tags: reactjs, warnings, autoprefixer

I am getting one warning like below when building my react application,

```
autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead
```

My package.json is like

```
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",


"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "last 1 ie version"
    ]
  },
```

As it is module related warning and not ours, how we resolve this warning. Kindly advice.